# Spring boot 2: Mapping addResourceHandler for each language returns 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to set-up to serve the static content based on the language param in the URL and I'm getting `404`, what mapping is wrong in the following code?

[image]

```
private PathResourceResolver getResolver() {
        return new PathResourceResolver() {
            @Override
            protected Resource resolveResourceInternal(HttpServletRequest request, String requestPath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
                logger.info("REQ PATH :: " + requestPath + "   " + locations);
                return super.resolveResourceInternal(request, requestPath, locations, chain); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        };
    }
```

And static folder structure:

[image]

Below is the complete logs that shows `404` when I try to access URL `https://localhost:8443/fr`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue, if others have faced similar issue below solution worked for me.

`addResourceLocations` path must end with `/` else the `StringUtils` `applyRelativePath` method will remove the last part of the path provided, in my case `en|fr|de..`

```
    /**
     * Apply the given relative path to the given Java resource path,
     * assuming standard Java folder separation (i.e. "/" separators).
     * @param path the path to start from (usually a full file path)
     * @param relativePath the relative path to apply
     * (relative to the full file path above)
     * @return the full file path that results from applying the relative path
     */
    public static String applyRelativePath(String path, String relativePath) {
        int separatorIndex = path.lastIndexOf(FOLDER_SEPARATOR);
        if (separatorIndex != -1) {
            String newPath = path.substring(0, separatorIndex);
            if (!relativePath.startsWith(FOLDER_SEPARATOR)) {
                newPath += FOLDER_SEPARATOR;
            }
            return newPath + relativePath;
        }
        else {
            return relativePath;
        }
    }
```